# Replace line from one list with one line from another list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

How can I replace a line from one list with another line from another list and keep the ID if the word in the 2nd column is repeated?
The word `amõ`, `resé`, and `.`, `,` are in the first list but the rest is empty. The data contains in the list below, I need to add it to the first one. How can I do it?

```
5       amõ     _       _       _       _       _       _       _       _
12      resé    _       _       _       _       _       _       _       _
2       βé      _       _       _       _       _       _       _       _
5       mo'ãmi  _       _       _       _       _       _       _       _
7       ?       _       _       _       _       _       _       _       _
8       .       _       _       _       _       _       _       _       _
```

---

```
6       ,       ,       PUNCT   punct   _       _       _       _       _
8       amõ     amõ     PRON    pro     PronType=Ind    _       _       _      _
10      kotɨ    kotɨ    ADP     posp    _       _       _       _       _
11      .       .       PUNCT   punct   _       _       _       _       _
13      ?       ?       PUNCT   punct   _       _       _       _       _
8       resé    esé     ADP     posp    _        _       _       _      _
```

Comment: add proper tags to your question. looks like a data frame.

Comment: what output are you expecting?